# Apache Tomcat MimeTypes - Any way to fetch them?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, mime-types, servlet-filters

I'm writing a filter for Apache Tomcat, I was wondering if there's a way to fetch the mimetypes placed in the /conf/web.xml file configuration file without reading the xml file explicitly. Is there anything available in the Apache Tomcat libraries perhaps?

Comment: What exactly do you need this information for? There may be better ways than hacking in some containerspecific code which would make your webapp unportable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the `tomcat/conf/web.xml`:

```
<!-- ======================== Introduction ============================== -->
<!-- This document defines default values for *all* web applications      -->
<!-- loaded into this instance of Tomcat.  As each application is         -->
<!-- deployed, this file is processed, followed by the                    -->
<!-- "/WEB-INF/web.xml" deployment descriptor from your own               -->
<!-- applications.                                                        -->
```

So they are available through the [ServletContext.getMimeType](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMimeType%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, 
        final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final ServletContext servletContext = req.getServletContext();
    final String mimeType = servletContext.getMimeType("filename.txt");
    ...
}
```

I haven't found any other public API for getting the whole MIME type mapping. If you really need
it you can get the complete list of the extensions with this ugly hack:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;

...

// ugly reflection hack - do NOT use
final RequestFacade tomcatRequestFacade = (RequestFacade) req;
final Class<? extends RequestFacade> requestFacadeClass = 
    tomcatRequestFacade.getClass();
try {
    final Field field = requestFacadeClass.getDeclaredField("request");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    final Request tomcatRequest = (Request) field.get(tomcatRequestFacade);
    final StandardContext standardContext = 
        (StandardContext) tomcatRequest.getContext();
    final String[] mappings = standardContext.findMimeMappings();
    logger.info("mapping list: {}", Arrays.asList(mappings));
} catch (final Exception e) {
    logger.error("", e);
}
```

It works on Tomcat 7.0.21. Since it uses Tomcat's internal classes there is no guarantee that it will work with other Tomcat versions.

Note that you still need to call the `ServletContext.getMimeType` to get the MIME types.

The required maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.21</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I understood that the OP wanted to fetch them all into some `Map` or something. But this is indeed one of the "better ways" I was talking about in my comment to the question :)

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, I know, but I didn't want to use container specific code with reflection and I haven't found any public API. Anyway, I've written it just for fun :-)

Comment: I need this information in order to check whether the requested resource has a known mime type to the server, I just had no idea that req.getServletContext().getMimeType() does just that...
I was using:
URLConnection.getFileNameMap().getContentTypeFor(), but I wanted something which was Server specific...

Will the previous do what i'm after?

Comment: Yes, `req.getServletContext().getMimeType()` works from `tomcat/conf/web.xml` and the `WEB-INF/web.xml` of the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
        Properties defaultMimeMappings = new Properties();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = Tomcat.class.getResourceAsStream("MimeTypeMappings.properties");
            defaultMimeMappings.load(is);
            for (Map.Entry<Object, Object>  entry: defaultMimeMappings.entrySet()) {
                // context.addMimeMapping((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
                // do what you need here or just the use the properties w/o this loop
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(sm.getString("tomcat.defaultMimeTypeMappingsFail"), e);
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        }
```

Straight from org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addDefaultMimeTypeMappings()

If you look at the properties file, it has everything I think you'd need:

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/MimeTypeMappings.properties

This way you can get all the file extensions for a specific mime type.